# JPA Hibernate foreign key is stored in the wrong table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I have this basic setup and I don't really understand, why I get the behavior that I'm getting

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@UserDefinition 
public class User {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userSeq", sequenceName = "ZSEQ_USER_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "userSeq")

@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ActivityForum activityForum;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

//ctor...
//getter/setter...
}
```

ActivityForum

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Actvity_Forum")
public class ActivityForum {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "afcSeq", sequenceName = "ZSEQ_af_ID",allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "afSeq")

@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "activityForum")
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;

//ctor...
//getter/setter...
}
```

Phone

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="PHONE")
public class Phone{
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "phoneSeq", sequenceName = "ZSEQ_phone_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "phoneSeq")

@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name ="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private User user;

//ctor...
//getter/setter...
}
```

This is the resulting DB-layout.

[image: DB-Layout]

I left some columns out of the src code to keep the post shorter.

Before I asked this question I did some research and found, that the foreign key gets stored in the table of the owner of the relationship. And the owner is determined by the @JoinColumn annotation. And It worked on the Phone ManyToOne Relationship.

Question: Why is the Key stored in the User table. And not in the Activity table.

What I am working with.
Java 11
Quarkus LTS
Gradle 6.71
MySQL DB

Comment: mappedBy is always specified in the not owning side of the relation. Also seems strange to me that you don t get an error specifying mappedBy and joinColumn on the same property

Comment: `mappedBy` tells JPA 'hey, don't look for any mappings here, this association is already **mapped by** such and such field in the other class!' JPA, of course, obliges, and so your `@JoinColumn` is getting ignored

Comment: Thanks for that. That fixed my Problem. If one of you wants to post it as an Answer I will gladly accept it. Otherwise, I will write an answer with a more detailed explanation myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments of @vincendep and @crizzis I quickly found my mistake.

[Explanation](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby):
Defining the direction of the relationship between entities has no impact on the database mapping. It only defines the directions in which we use that relationship in our domain model.

For a bidirectional relationship, we usually define:

the owning side
inverse or the referencing side
The @JoinColumn annotation helps us specify the column we'll use for joining an entity association or element collection. On the other hand, the **mappedBy** attribute is used to define the **referencing side (non-owning side)** of the relationship.

Code changes:

User

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private ActivityForum activityForum;
```

ActivityForum

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;
```

The Resulting DB Layout:

[image: new DB Layout]